# Gtk-WARNING when loading gedit from shell

Tags: command-line, 12.10, gtk, gedit

I've just upgraded from 12.04 to 12.10. I don't know why but I can never avoid upgrading.

Anyway, every time I load gedit from the shell I get this:

```
(gedit:2696): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:85:17: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(gedit:2696): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:196:17: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(gedit:2696): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:234:17: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(gedit:2696): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:295:17: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(gedit:2696): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:332:17: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
```

It goes on and on, I didn't want to post it all as it is too long. I remember having a similar problem before that I fixed by installing `get2-engines-pixbuf`, but it is already installed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the creator of the theme failed to indicate the unit 'pixels' in some places.
the only solution is to modify the theme's configuartion.

Comment: You're right, I have no idead how to do it. Just changes back to Ambience. THanks!